# How to display a single post with wordpress menu?

Tags: content-management-system, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have converted a joomla website to wordpress. All categories and joomla articles are converted as wordpress categories and blog post. Now I want to show this posts (articles) with different menus. But I saw I can assign catagories in word press menu. But How can I display a single post with a menu ?

Like I have about us post , for which I want to create a menu. How can I do that ? I can convert those to pages. But I dont want to loose tags and URLs . Can anyone help please ?

Thanks

Comment: you can use custom links in wordpress

Answer (score 4):

You can add any post to a menu from the "posts" box in the menu admin screen. If you don't see that box, go to the screen options for the menu screen and check "posts".

Answer (score 0):

There is an option named Custom Links in wordpress menu configuration. Just name label as "About Us", and give your post link in url field.

Comment: But like joomla it doesn't take only last parameters like index.php?your_url I need to post the full http://localhost/your_url which will take lots of time when I will make my website live. Is there any solution ?

Comment: i didn't get ur comment, please elaborate. What do you want? you want to add posts in menus, you can done manually one by one from above option. or you can enable posts in menu by "Screen Option" like this - http://i.imgur.com/DGryl1H.jpg . Just check post option too.

Answer (score 0):

create separate page template for every single menu. In these page templates write a php code to fetch content from single category. Create pages in admin and assign a page template to each page into admin. This will fetch content from different category on different menu that u want.